# How to split list into separate lines?

Tags: python

I have a list which is made by the following code:

```
[ self.directory + "/" + file for file in os.listdir(self.directory) ]
```

When i print this list out it appears on one line separated by commas.

How do I split this list so that when printed each listed item appears on its own line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, don't use `dir + "/" + file` - use `os.path.join(dir, file)`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you want the items in a list in separate lines, you could have done

```
your_list = [ self.directory + "/" + file for file in os.listdir(self.directory) ]

for e in your_list:
    print e
```

or use `str.split`

```
print '\n'.join(your_list)
```

Comment: use the for loop way. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print ('\n'.join(['1','2','3','4']))
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: how would I use this when printing the list out in a listbox using tkinter?

Comment: nvm i worked it out. thanks

Comment: with join, you can create a string: `st='\n'.join(your_list)` Then send `st` to tkinter.